# the lowest low of some days

Tags: arrays, pine-script

I'm trying to find a way to get a signal-point on the chart everytime the bar is a new 15-days low.

Thanks for help!

```
//@version=5
indicator('15-Days-Low', overlay=true)

bars_back = input(15)

ll = ta.lowest(bars_back) //15-d-low
tl = ta.lowest(source=low, length=1) //todays low
lb = ta.lowestbars(bars_back)  //lowest bar since when? (negative number)

plotchar(tl < ll, char='•', color=color.fuchsia, size=size.tiny, location=location.belowbar)
```

I tried to find the lowest low of the last 15 days, compare it to the low of today, and plot a char if the todays low is the lowest of the last 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

`ta.lowest()` will include the current bar. So, you can directly compare it with `low`.

```
ll = ta.lowest(bars_back) //15-d-low
is_lowest = (low == ll)

plotshape(is_lowest)
```